# Update a live service which is currently running 24x7

Tags: wcf, web-services, service, amazon-web-services

Can anybody suggest how to update a web-service /wcf service holding live transactions without any downtime?

Please don't suggest updating at off peak hours, because our service runs 24x7 and transactions may run any period of time.

So what is the best way to update such service with some changes so that current transactions don't get affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use load balancing to prevent errors and keep the site up during updates. For this to work you need at least two servers behind a load balancer that sends traffic to whichever server is up. My procedure for updating my sites is:

Tell "Server A" to start serving an error page at the URL that the load balancer pings. This tells the load balancer to stop sending traffic to this server.
Wait 30 seconds or so until traffic stops hitting the server.
Update the code on this server.
Tell the server to stop serving an error page at the ping URL.
Wait until that server is getting traffic again.
Repeat steps 1-5 with "Server B".

Comment: +1, that is a good alternative. Can i use Load balancing by making two instances in same server?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience... i use a Git server and a local machine to edit the code to make sure it all works, and then push to the server, then pull on the live site, and then it has 0 down time....

Answer (score 0):

Without 0 seconds downtime, It is not possible.
Least you can do is Update the web-services, test that thoroughly at say staging server. Verify and be sure updates are working perfect.

Update the services- part (a xyz.war file in my case) and re-start the server for getting this into effect.
If there is any DB or other changes involved in this process, i make a script of that and test the same at staging server before going live.

Just one suggestion: Take proper backup of current live server for the otherwise case.

Comment: Hi Aditya ! I think i already mentioned that we can't down the service or restart it. because what about those running transaction which are running continuously

Comment: Hi Empire: I just shared my knowledge here, and i see Donstack has provided better solution on this. With 0 downtime updates to live server, i still doubt is achievable. I look forward for solution at this page. Best Luck.